# One of the main things to do is to never throw garbage and factory waste in/into the sea

Tags: prepositions

> One of the main things to do is to never throw garbage and factory waste **in** the sea.

or

> One of the main things to do is to never throw garbage and factory waste **into** the sea.

Answer (score 2):

While there are other issues with your sentences here, the correct word is "into" not "in". It may seem that these two words are interchangeable, they are not.

An object may be "in" the sea but it's not "into" the sea.
An object may be thrown "into" the sea but it's not thrown "in" the sea.

The latter implies that the object was in the sea to start with and someone picked it up and threw it.  While that's possible, it's unlikely you meant to say that.

As far as the other issues.  Saying this as "things to do is to never" is awkward.  I believe this could be better stated as:

> "One of the main things to avoid is throwing garbage and factory waste
> into the sea."